# Azure container registry gets down uncertainly

Tags: azure, azure-container-registry

This error has no actual reproduce steps and I get this error very randomly. Due to below mentioned error, my deployment script fails unexpected.

[image: Error Screenshot]

Above error message looks little blurred, unfortunately I don't have error in text right now but will copy next time surely.

Answer (score 0):

If you could help with the broader steps, it would help us narrow this down.
Are you seeing this when automating the creation of a registry with the same name? 
When creating and deleting a registry, dns caching can cause the above failure as the dns name wasn't fully cleaned up when you attempt to re-create a registry of the same name. We've seen this when doing demos, including Scott Hanselmans recent recording. We're looking into cleaning up the error to be more specific, but please advise if this is the issue, or some other flow.
Steve